# AsOrdered() not working

Tags: c#, parallel-processing

I'm trying use `AsParallell()` with `AsOrdered()` method, but always I see unordered results.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Parallel
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<String> cities = new List<String>() {
                "Barcelona",
                "Valencia",
                "Sevilla",
                "Zaragoza",
                "Málaga",
                "Murcia",
                "Palma",
                "Las Palmas de Gran Canaria",
                "Alicante",
                "Madrid",
                "Córdoba",
                "Valladolid",
                "Tarrasa",
                "Vigo",
                "Gijón",
                "Cartagena",
                "Hospitalet de Llobregat",
                "Vitoria",
                "La Coruña",
                "Granada",
                "Elche",
                "Oviedo",
                "Badalona"
            };

            var filtered = cities.AsParallel().AsOrdered().Where(c => c.ToUpper().StartsWith("B") || c.ToUpper().EndsWith("A")).ToArray();

            Console.WriteLine("Cities starting with \"B\" or ends with \"A\"");

            foreach (String city in filtered) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine(city);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
Cities starting with "B" or ends with "A"
Barcelona
Valencia
Sevilla
Zaragoza
Málaga
Murcia
Palma
Las Palmas de Gran Canaria
Córdoba
Tarrasa
Cartagena
Vitoria
La Coruña
Granada
Badalona

Press any key to continue...
```

Whats wrong?

I'm using Visual Studio in Mac, Net Core project.

Thanks

Comment: Almost correct, always provide _expected_ results as well as the actual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AsOrdered()` just maintains the *original* order of the items in the `List<string>`. If you want to order the items alphabetically you could use the `OrderBy` method:

```
var filtered = cities.AsParallel().Where(c => c.ToUpper().StartsWith("B") || c.ToUpper().EndsWith("A")).OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

`AsOrdered` does not mean it will sort your collection. `AsOrdered` means it will *preserve* existing ordering. Because your collection is initially unordered - your results are unordered too.

If you will do

```
 cities.Sort();
```

before parallel query - your results will be ordered. However, if you do this but *remove* `AsParallel` - your results are not guaranteed to be ordered.